# adding Courier font to project

Tags: android, fonts

I would like to use Courier font for some of my TextView and am stuck. I do:

```
Typeface face=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "font/Courier.ttf");
```

but this doesnt work of course as there isnt any font in that folder.
Where can I find android core fonts, resp. is there a site where I can download fonts to add to my project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you noted, there isn't any font in that folder. There are a million font sites out there which you can find easily through Google. Just download the ttf file, create a font folder under your assets folder, and put the ttf file in there. If you're using Windows, usually you can copy files from C:\Windows\Fonts\ or something like that. Just make sure you have distribution rights to those particular font files.

Comment: +1, especially for the distribution rights part, it's an easy thing to overlook